# Select2 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'status' in undefined on ajax request

Tags: javascript, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make a select2 with ajax on my Laravel project and this is happening:

[error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekfk5.png)

[error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axiwm.png)

This is my js:

```
import 'select2';

let baseurl = window.location.origin;

$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#produtos-select2').select2({
        multiple: true,
        ajax: {
            url: baseurl + "produtos/ajax",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            type: 'get',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    nome: params.term
                }
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }, 
            cache: true,
        },
        status: 0
    });
});
```

The action of the route has this return:

return Produto::select('id', 'nome', 'valor')->get();

I tried to find anyone else with this problem and didn't

Comment: What is the actual response your AJAX request received? Use your browser dev tools, network panel, to check.

Comment: Please post code directly into your question and use the formatting feature.

Comment: @CBroe it's just a standard collection of the model

Comment: As actual JSON, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the status: 0 line from the configuration object, as it's not a valid option for Select2  and Modifie the processResults function to return the results in the correct structure. Select2 expects the results to be inside a results property

```
$('#produtos-select2').select2({
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
        url: baseurl + "produtos/ajax",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        type: 'get',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                nome: params.term
            }
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data // Make sure the data structure matches what Select2 expects
            };
        },
        cache: true,
    }
});
```